# angular.js:13294 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cityResourceProvider <- cityResource <- cityListCtrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with angularJS for the first time and working with services and factories to create a web api REST call. I'm currently getting this error before the call is even made:

```
angular.js:13294 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cityResourceProvider <- cityResource <- cityListCtrl
```

app.js

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("politicalHub",["common.services"]);

}());
```

common.services.js

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"])
        .constant("appSettings", {
            serverPath: "http://localhost:49828/"
        });
});
```

cityResource.js

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    function cityResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "api/City");
    }

    angular
        .module("common.services", [])
        .factory("cityResource",
        [
            "$resource",
            "appSettings",
            cityResource
        ]);
}());
```

cityListCtrl.js (Controller)

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    function cityListCtrl(cityResource) {
        var vm = this;

        cityResource.query(function(data) {
            vm.cities = data;
        });
    }

    angular
        .module("politicalHub",[])
        .controller("cityListCtrl",
        ["cityResource", cityListCtrl]);


}());
```

html

```
 <form>
              <div ng-controller="cityListCtrl as vm" align="center">
                  <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding: 0">
                      <select ng-options="city.city_name for city in cities" ng-model="city.name" class="form-control">

                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

   var app = angular.module("politicalHub",["common.services"]);

}());
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed to call `common.services.js` as its IIFE function should get call by itself

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"])
        .constant("appSettings", {
            serverPath: "http://localhost:49828/"
        });
})();
```

Comment: I made this change within common.services.js and I'm still getting the same error